# Out-File and carriage returns

Tags: powershell, newline, carriage-return, powershell-cmdlet

If I have a program, for example this Go program:

```golang
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   fmt.Print("North East\n")
   fmt.Print("South West\n")
}
```

This program produces no carriage returns at all, only newlines. However if I do this:

```
prog.exe > prog.txt
```

PowerShell takes it upon itself to add carriage returns to every line. I only want PowerShell to faithfully output what my program created, nothing more. So I tried this instead:

```
prog.exe | Out-File -NoNewline prog.txt
```

and PowerShell didn't add carriage returns, but it went ahead and removed the newlines too. How do I do what I am trying to do? Update: based on an answer, this seems to do it:

```
start -rso prog.txt prog.exe
```

Comment: Just for reference, Go's print won't produce a new line by default right?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's an encoding issue? Try to use `-utf8` and see if there's any issues with that.

Comment: Pardon me. I'm on my phone and didn't realize I forgot the actual parameter name. It's `-Enconding UTF8`.

Comment: There are things you could try that won't look pretty but may work like `(prog.exe | Out-String -Stream).trim() >> prog.txt`

Comment: `PS 6+` also has `Out-String -NoNewline`: Removes all newlines from output generated by the PowerShell formatter. Newlines that are part of the string objects are preserved.

Comment: Don't edit (incidental variations of) answers you've been given into your question - it's both redundant and confusing.

Comment: Don't cross-post at the PowerShell GitHub repo - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15301. SO is the right place for seeking clarification of the by-design behavior. By contrast, the GitHub repo is the right place for reporting bugs based on observed deviations from the by-design behavior, or feature requests based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is due to the behavior of redirecting output. It's split up into separate lines wherever a newline is detected, but when Powershell joins the lines again, it will use both newline *and* carriage return (the Windows default).

This should not be an issue though, if you redirect the output *directly*. So this should give you the expected behavior:

```
Start-Process prog.exe -RedirectStandardOutput prog.txt
```

Comment: Nicely done, though I suggest adding `-Wait` to ensure synchronous operation. Another option, which has the advantage of directly reporting the external program's exit code (via `$LASTEXITCODE`) is to delegate to the platform-native shell's binary pipeline. On Windows: `cmd /c "prog.exe > prog.txt"`; on Unix,  `sh -c "prog.exe > prog.txt"`.
Or, generalized:
`$nativeShell = ('sh', 'cmd')[$env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT'];
$commandOption = ('-c', '/c')[$env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT'];
& $nativeShell $commandOption "date > prog.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Note that out-file defaults to utf16 encoding, vs set-content.

```
"hi`nthere`n" | out-file file -NoNewline

format-hex file


           Path: C:\users\admin\foo\file

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   FF FE 68 00 69 00 0A 00 74 00 68 00 65 00 72 00  .þh.i...t.h.e.r.
00000010   65 00 0A 00                                      e...
```

Ok, my first Go program:

```
(go run .) -join "`n" | set-content file -NoNewline
```

The problem is windows programs output carriage return and linefeed.  This would work fine, or no carriage return would work in linux or osx powershell.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   fmt.Print("North East\r\n")
   fmt.Print("South West\r\n")
}
```

```
go run . > file
```

Actually this problem is resolved in powershell 7.  The file will end up having \r\n even if the go code doesn't.

Comment: It's different, though, if you redirect the stdout from an *external* program.